# Python - beautifulsoup - how to deal with missing closing tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I would like to scrape the table from html code using beautifulsoup. A snippet of the html is shown below. When using `table.findAll('tr')` I get the entire table and not only the rows. (probably because the closing tags are missing from the html code?)

```
  <TABLE COLS=9 BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=0>
  <TR><TD><B>Artikelbezeichnung</B>
  <TD><B>Anbieter</B>
  <TD><B>Menge</B>
  <TD><B>Taxe-EK</B>
  <TD><B>Taxe-VK</B>
  <TD><B>Empf.-VK</B>
  <TD><B>FB</B>
  <TD><B>PZN</B>
  <TD><B>Nachfolge</B>

  <TR><TD>ACTIQ 200 Mikrogramm Lutschtabl.m.integr.Appl.
  <TD>Orifarm
  <TD ID=R>     30 St
  <TD ID=R>  266,67
  <TD ID=R>  336,98
  <TD>&nbsp;
  <TD>&nbsp;
  <TD>12516714
  <TD>&nbsp;

  </TABLE>
```

Here is my python code to show what I am struggling with:

```
     soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
     table = soup.findAll("table")[0]
     rows = table.find_all('tr')
     for tr in rows:
         print(tr.text)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in their [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) `html5lib` parses the document as the web browser does (Like `lxml`in this case). It'll try to fix your document tree by adding/closing tags when needed.

In your example I've used lxml as the parser and it gave the following result:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
table = soup.findAll("table")[0]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in rows:
    print(tr.get_text(strip=True))
```

Note that `lxml` added html & body tags because they weren't present in the source (It'll try to create a well formed document as previously state).